# Problems while calculating value of sine with Taylor series

Tags: c++, c, taylor-series

I'm trying to calculate

[image: sin x]

Using the following code.

```
#define PI 3.14
double ans;
double input1;

void toRad() {
    input1 = input1 * PI / 180.0;
}

void sine(void) {
    toRad();
    ans = input1;
    int i = 1;
    for (; i < 15; i++) {
        if (i % 2 == 0)
            ans = ans + (ans * input1 * input1) / 2 * i * (2 * i + 1);
        else
            ans = ans - (ans * input1 * input1) / 2 * i * (2 * i + 1);
    }
    printf("%lf", ans);
}
```

I used iterative operations instead of `pow` and factorial functions to get more precise values and more iterations.

But, for some reason, I got different outputs like `-4000000E`. What can be the problem of this code?

Comment: And what is the problem?

Comment: Omg, forgot to ask question,
it outputs values like 2400000
what's wrong with this code

Comment: Why is `ans` a global variable? can't you just return it from `sine?` as `sin()` function does?

Comment: Because, it's only a part of my program -it's eaiser for my rest program-, of course, return can be used but, i don't think it'll change result.

Comment: Consider using `M_PI` from `math.h` (just to not reinvent the wheel). Also, you may want to rewrite your `toRad()` function like this: `double toRad(double in) { return in * PI / 180.0; }`

Comment: you are putting parenthesis to group the numerator factors, but not de denominator ones, so you are indeed evaluating the expression `(ans*input1*input1)*(i*(2*i + 1)) / 2`, group the factors in the denominator also.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you have made a small mistake in writing the logic.check yourself until i=4.

```
     if (i % 2 == 0)
        ans = ans + (ans * input1 * input1) / 2 * i * (2 * i + 1);
    else
        ans = ans - (ans * input1 * input1) / 2 * i * (2 * i + 1);
```

instead of this you should create a factorial function so that it can be replaced by

```
    if (i % 2 == 0)
        ans = ans + (ans * input1 * input1) / factorial(2 * i + 1);
    else
        ans = ans - (ans * input1 * input1) / factorial(2 * i + 1);
```